# Executing SPROC - Returning Value = -1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a SPROC set up to validate login credentials but I can't seem to get it to return the correct value when I execute it from my code. It keeps returning a value of '-1' even when I'm entering in the correct username and password combination when I try executing it from C# but it works perfectly fine when I execute it straight from SSMS.

**SPROC**

```
USE [database]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[usp_ReadUserLogin]
  @LoginUsername VARCHAR(50),
  @LoginPassword VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @Salt CHAR(25);
  DECLARE @PasswordSalt VARCHAR(125);
  DECLARE @PasswordHash VARBINARY(255);  

  SELECT @Salt = [dbo].[users].[salt], @PasswordHash = [dbo].[users].[password] 
  FROM [dbo].[users] WHERE [dbo].[users].[username] = @LoginUsername;

  SET @PasswordSalt = @Salt + @LoginPassword;

  IF (HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @PasswordSalt) = @PasswordHash)
    RETURN 0; /*Match*/
  ELSE
    RETURN 1; /*No Match*/    
END;
GO
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(User u)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // this is check validity
        {
            using (WebFTS.Models.webftsEntities db = new WebFTS.Models.webftsEntities())
            {
                //Method 1 - Still returns value = -1
                //var sql = "EXEC [dbo].[usp_ReadUserLogin] @LoginUsername, @LoginPassword";
                //var usernameParam = new SqlParameter("@LoginUsername", u.username);
                //var passwordParam = new SqlParameter("@LoginPassword", u.password);
                //var query = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, usernameParam, passwordParam);

                //Method 2 - Still returns value = -1
                var query = db.usp_ReadUserLogin(u.username, u.password);

                if (query != 0)
                {
                    ViewBag.message = "Incorrect username and/or password.";
                }
                else
                {
                    var d = db.users.Where(model => model.username.Equals(u.username)).FirstOrDefault(); 
                    if (d != null)
                    {
                        Session["lid"] = d.user_id.ToString();
                        Session["lun"] = d.username.ToString();
                        return RedirectToAction("AfterLogin");
                    }
                }
            }                
        }
        return View(u);
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
     <div style="margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;">
         <table style="overflow:hidden;">
             <tr>
                 <td>Username</td>
                 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.username)</td>
                 <td><b>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.username)</b></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>Password</td>
                 <td>@Html.PasswordFor(a => a.password)  </td>
                 <td><b>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.password)</b></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Login" class="button" /></td>                 
             </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**SPROC (UPDATED)**

```
USE [database]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[usp_ReadUserLogin]
  @LoginUsername VARCHAR(50),
  @LoginPassword VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
  --SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @userid INT;
  DECLARE @Salt CHAR(25);
  DECLARE @PasswordSalt VARCHAR(125);
  DECLARE @PasswordHash VARBINARY(255);  

  SELECT @userid = [dbo].[users].[user_id], @Salt = [dbo].[users].[salt], @PasswordHash = [dbo].[users].[password]  
  FROM [dbo].[users] WHERE [dbo].[users].[username] = @LoginUsername;

  SET @PasswordSalt = @Salt + @LoginPassword;

  IF (HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @PasswordSalt) = @PasswordHash)
     SELECT @userid; /*Match*/
  ELSE
     SELECT 0; /*No Match*/   
END;
GO
```

**CONTROLLER (UPDATED)**

```
System.Nullable<int> query = db.ReadUserLogin(u.username, u.password).SingleOrDefault();

if (query == 0)
    ViewBag.message = "Incorrect username and/or password.";
else if (query.HasValue)
{
     //follow the rest of the code to select the user.
}
```

Thanks to **Dude Pascalou** I was able to fix my issue. The [link he provided](http://www.devtoolshed.com/using-stored-procedures-entity-framework-scalar-return-values) is the answer. I've also updated the code so if anyone needs it, they can see the before and after. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it work, you may replace `RETURN` by `SELECT` and remove the `SET NOCOUNT ON;` statement.

Comment: I tried that but it still returning a value of '-1' for both valid and invalid logins.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your updated SP ? Also, I assume you are using Entity Framework with method 2 ? Then, try to follow the steps described here : http://www.devtoolshed.com/using-stored-procedures-entity-framework-scalar-return-values

Comment: The steps in the link does work! (And I updated the code above.) But when I test for a false login credentials, it's unable to return a nullable value. Does it have to do with the way the SPROC it set up?

Comment: I've edited the code accordingly and now it works for both correct and incorrect login credentials. Thank you!